# Setting global settings for JQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently using this plugin - [jQuery TableExport](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Exporting-Html-Tables-To-CSV-XLS-XLSX-Text-TableExport.html)

However I'm unable to override the global settings when trying to use this code provided to change the default file name -

```
$.fn.tableExport.defaultFileName = "myDownload";
```

above, underneath and inside the

`$("table").tableExport();`

However it either doesn't change the name or the buttons don't show up at all (it breaks) Can anyone let me know where I should be putting these global settings for them to work?

`$("table").tableExport();` does work, however, I'd like to change the global settings and the code they provided doesn't seem to do so. I think I'm doing something wrong with the placement of the code.

Comment: Could you explain in more details? i.e. regard the code that you have tried, to allow more people helping you.

Comment: @SaidbakR I've added more explanation of the code. The link has the full plugin and may give you a better idea of what I'm talking about.